# Is the definition: (a,b) = {a, {b}} equivalent to the definition of an ordered pair?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

!the first question is the one relevant: you need to explain/prove if the definitions given are correct]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZOtI.jpg)

I need to determine whether the first 3 definitions are equivalent to the definition of ordered couples, and to explain why.

i'm taking the class of "introduction to set theory" for math b.a students, so the question is not under the assumption of ZFC

Comment: To be a valid definition of an ordered pair, it is necessary and sufficient that given an "ordered pair" object, you can extract the first and the second component, and for every $a$ and $b$ you can create an ordered pair object which you can decode using that extraction procedure. Can you do that with those three definitions, whatever $a$ and $b$ are?

Comment: so i'd say for the second defenion that the answer is yes - given that a \in {0, a} and b \in  {1, b}. correct?

Comment: Did you try your TA and their office hours?

Comment: I haven't, since it's a holiday atm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. (0,1) = (1,0)
2. ({a},b) = ({b},a)

Comment: The second of these is a good counterexample. The first depends on a common but not necessary definition of $0$ and $1$ as particular sets.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the two cases
$$
a_1 = \{\{x\}\}, b_1 = x\\
a_2 = \{x\}, b_2 = \{x\}
$$
I have used one of the rows above to make one of your "ordered pairs" $(a_i, b_i)$, and the result I get is
$$
(a_i, b_i) = \{\{x\}, \{\{x\}\}\}
$$
Can you tell me whether I've used $i = 1$ or $i = 2$?

Comment: As an important side note: this assumes ZFC. More specifically the axiom of foundation. Without it you cannot conclude that $x\neq \{x\}$.

Comment: @freakish That can be remedied by specifying exactly what $x$ is, like $x=\varnothing$. But sure, if we want this to be a counterexample for any $x$, then that would require something like the axiom of foundation.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you wouldn't be able to prove that even for $x=\emptyset$. Subtleties about being "non-empty" and $x=\{x\}$ are well hidden behind the axiom of foundation. And yes, there might not be (provable) counterexample outside of ZF. That's all I'm saying.

Comment: @freakish Even without foundation, you can prove that $\{\varnothing\}\neq\{\{\varnothing\}\}$, and so on.

Comment: Unlikely. Please show me.

Comment: @freakish Assume for contradiction that $\{\varnothing\}=\{\{\varnothing\}\}$. Then, by definition of $=$, we have $$\forall z(z\in\{\varnothing\}\iff z\in\{\{\varnothing\}\})$$But this is clearly false, as $z=\{\varnothing\}$ shows. Thus we have $\{\varnothing\}\neq\{\{\varnothing\}\}$.

Comment: Well only if $z\neq\emptyset$. But still what remains to show is that $\emptyset\neq\{\emptyset\}$.

Comment: @freakish And then we employ the same tactic there, with $z=\varnothing$. We have $\varnothing\in \{\varnothing\}$, but $\varnothing\notin \varnothing$. And this time there is no weight shifting, because $z\in \varnothing$ is never true for any $z$, while $z\in\{\varnothing\}$ is true for some $z$.

Comment: i think you might be right. I have to think about it more though.

Comment: @freakish: To put it another (hopefully clearer) way, if $\{\emptyset\}=\{\{\emptyset\}\},$ then by Extensionality, we have $\emptyset=\{\emptyset\}.$ But this is impossible by Extensionality, since $\emptyset\notin\emptyset$ and $\emptyset\in\{\emptyset\}.$

Comment: @CameronBuie That two equal sets contain the same elements is not from extensionality, that's from the definition of $=$. Extensionality is the converse, i.e. that if two sets contain the same elements, then they are equal.

Comment: Oops! Thank you, Arthur. I meant to use the converse, but thought I was using the contrapositive. :-/

@freakish: As Arthur points out, my comment above should read "... But this is impossible [by definition of equality], since...."

Answer (score 2):

> I need to determine whether the first 3 definitions are equivalent to the definition of ordered couples, and to explain why.

For that you have to know what an "ordered couple" actually means and how those different definitions can be verified? I assume this is the property you are looking at:

> **Ordered pair equality:** $(a,b) = (c,d)\text{ if and only if }a=c\text{ and }b=d$

Note the subtle difference between this property and equality between sets:

> **Set equality:** $\{a, b\}=\{c, d\}\text{ if and only if }(a = c\text{ and }b=d)\textbf{ or }(a = d\text{ and }b=c)$

This is not a standard definition, more like a consequence of "$A\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq A$" which is easier to understand when both sets have $1-2$ elements. Anyway it will be useful later.

Another important thing is that the underlying axiomatic system matters. We often assume ZF (or sometimes ZFC) implicitly but I have a tendency to be more explicit. Because you see, ZF is one of the most popular models. And in ZF the equality $x=\{x\}$ cannot hold, no matter what $x$ is. But there are systems in which $x=\{x\}$ holds, most notably ZF without the axiom of foundation. This will become important as we will see soon. And it is far from a trivial observation.

**Everything that follows is assumed to be under ZF.**

---

So let's have a look at those 3 cases:

> **(1)** $(a,b) := \{\{0,a\}, \{1, b\}\}$

I assume here that $0\neq 1$, e.g. $0=\emptyset$ and $1=\{\emptyset\}$. It really doesn't matter what $0, 1$ are as long as they are distinct.

Assume that $(a,b)=(c,d)$. Then $\{\{0,a\}, \{1, b\}\}=\{\{0,c\}, \{1, d\}\}$. So under that assumption the equivalent condition for the equality is:

$$\{0,a\}=\{0,c\}\text{ and }\{1,b\}=\{1,d\}$$
$$\textbf{or}$$
$$\{0,a\}=\{1,d\}\text{ and }\{1,b\}=\{0,c\}$$

The first "or" case implies that $a=c$ and $b=d$. What about the other one? It implies that $a=1, d=0$ and $b=0, c=1$ which means $a=c$ and $b=d$.

So this one is good, all paths lead to $a=c$ and $b=d$.

This definition is also known as *the Hausdorff's ordered pair*.

> **(2)** $(a,b) := \{a, \{b\}\}$

As others noted this fails since $(\{x\}, \{x\})=(\{\{x\}\}, x)$ and we can never have $x=\{x\}$ for $x=\emptyset$. Also in ZF this cannot happen for any other set (due to [the axiom of foundation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity)).

> **(3)** $(a,b) := \{ \{a\}, \{a, \{b\}\}\}$

Assume that $(a,b)=(c,d)$. In other words we have

$$\{a\} = \{c\}\text{ and }\{a, \{b\}\} = \{c, \{d\}\}$$
$$\textbf{or}$$
$$\{a\} = \{c, \{d\}\}\text{ and }\{a, \{b\}\} = \{c\}$$

The first "or" case obviously implies that $a=c$ and $b=d$. The other "or" case implies that $c=\{d\}$ (first "and" equality) and $a=\{b\}$ (second "and" equality). And then $a=c$ and $b=d$ follows. So this one is good as well.

Also note that the last one is very similar to *the Kuratowski's definition* of the ordered pair $(a,b)=\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$.

Comment: For 2, first all you need is that there is _some_ $x$ s.t. $x\ne\{x\}$, not that it can never happen. So all you need is e.g. $x=\varnothing$. Second, assuming that for some $x$ you have $x=\{x\}$ is *not* Russell's paradox, as you can have it in a model of ZF without foundation, while you don't have Russell's Paradox in ZF

Comment: @UrYa'ar I'm not sure what you mean by "is not Russell's paradox", I'm assuming full ZF (with the axiom of foundation) as stated at the begining. Also I would like to see the proof that $\emptyset\neq\{\emptyset\}$ in ZF without the axiom of foundation.

Comment: $\varnothing$ is defined as the set which has no elements. The set $\{\varnothing\}$ has an element - $\varnothing$. So $\varnothing\in\{\varnothing\}$ while $\varnothing\notin\varnothing$ so by Extensionality they are not the same.

Comment: Russell's paradox is a contradiction derived from the assumption that the class $\{x\mid x\notin x\}$ is a set. This contradiction does not arrise from assuming ZF$-$foundation+ there is a set satisfying $x=\{x\}$, unless ZF itself is inconsistent (see section II.9 in Kunen's new edition).

Comment: @UrYa'ar Fair enough, I've updated the answer.

Comment: @freakish if the question is not under zf - are this answers no longer apply when referring to the naive set theory?

Comment: @user3369096 it is very hard to determine anything in naive set theory. The concept of proving something becomes blurred. Definitions are blurred as well. So I don't have answer for that question. But I would not go down the naive road. As for weaker forms of ZF: the answer depends on axioms you assume. Everything is possible.

Comment: @even__n I believe that the only axiom you need in order to carry the arguments in 1 and 3 is the **Axiom of Extensionality**: $x=y \iff \forall z (z\in x \iff z\in y)$. This axiom is (IMO) the basis of the concept of a set, and I believe that in naive set theory it is also assumed, even if not explicitly. Even in NST you must have some definite way to determine whether two sets are the same, and that is Extensionality.  
For 2 you also need to have e.g. the empty set, which you probably always have in NST.

Comment: @UrYa'ar For (1) you need the existance of two distinct sets for which I believe you additionally need the axiom schema of specification and the existance of a (empty) set. For each definition you probably need the axiom of pairing as well. I'm not sure if the axiom of power set is needed to define $\{b\}$ from $b$, but possibly some axiom is needed for that as well. So anyway you need at least half of ZF to make the definitions and proofs meaningful.

Comment: @freakish Yes I thought I should add a comment about that - to make the **definition** and justify the fact that it is indeed a set you need more of ZF (but not half of it - pairing is enough to define $\{b\}$, and just one instance of separation/specification to get the empty set, and from there you just need pairing again).  
But in NST you just assume that all these are indeed sets, and given that assumption, I don't think the proof needs more than what I said. In particular, for the question of whether the proof would apply to NST, I think it doesn't really matter what kind of NST it is.

Answer (score 1):

If $a=\{y\}$ and $x=\{b\}$ then $\{a,\{b\}\}=\{x,\{y\}\}$ but it is evidently not necessary that $a=x$ and $b=y$.